# Can't install wine on ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: wine

```
[root ~]$ apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 brasero-cdrkit : Depends: libbrasero-media3-1 (= 3.10.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python : Depends: cairo-dock-plug-ins (>= 3.3.99.beta1.2.really.3.3.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 friends-twitter : Depends: friends
                   Depends: account-plugin-twitter but it is not going to be installed
 gdb : Depends: libpython3.4 (>= 3.4~b1) but it is not going to be installed
 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 : Depends: libpackagekit-glib2-16 (>= 0.8.12) but it is not going to be installed
 gir1.2-rb-3.0 : Depends: librhythmbox-core8 (>= 3.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 indicator-datetime : Depends: libecal-1.2-16 (>= 3.7.90) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libedataserver-1.2-18 (>= 3.5.91) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: indicator-applet but it is not going to be installed or
                                  indicator-renderer
                      Recommends: evolution-data-server but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: geoclue-ubuntu-geoip but it is not going to be installed or
                                  geoclue-provider
 indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 7.82) but it is not going to be installed
 libaccounts-qt5-1 : Depends: libaccounts-glib0 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
 libnice10 : Depends: libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 (>= 0.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libnm-util2 : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                        libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1) but it is not going to be installed
 liboauth0 : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                      libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1) but it is not going to be installed
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: liboxideqtcore0 (= 1.8.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: liboxideqtquick0 (= 1.8.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libpeas-1.0-0 : Depends: libpython2.7 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpython3.4 (>= 3.4~b1) but it is not going to be installed
 libpython-stdlib : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libpython3-stdlib : Depends: libpython3.4-stdlib (>= 3.4.0-0~) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1) but it is not going to be installed
 libsmbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8) but it is not going to be installed
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: network-manager (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
 python2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libpython3.4 (>= 3.4~b1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3.4 : Depends: libpython3.4-stdlib (= 3.4.0-2ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin : Depends: libqt5svg5 but it is not going to be installed
                                           Depends: libthumbnailer0 (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 rhythmbox-mozilla : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 signon-plugin-password : Depends: signond but it is not going to be installed
 sqlite3:i386 : Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 system-config-printer-gnome : Depends: python-libxml2 but it is not going to be installed
 telepathy-haze : Depends: libpurple0 (>= 1:2.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: gir1.2-webkit-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 13.10-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-mediascanner2 : Depends: mediascanner2.0 but it is not going to be installed
 unity8-private : Depends: libusermetricsoutput1 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1)
 yelp : Depends: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libyelp0 (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What can I do?

Comment: As far as I know, you're supposed to run `sudo apt-get install wine`. I'm also fairly certain that Wine 1.6 is currently the latest full release

Answer (score 1):

Wine 1.6 is the **stable** version.

Wine 1.7 is  the most recent - but **beta** - version.

This means they will periodically suffer from regressions and an update may break functionality.

If the stable Wine version 1.16 works flawlessly you should not install and use the beta packages.

Refer [here](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

If you nevertheless want to install the beta version -

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You have selected the wrong package version.

You need to install wine1.6.

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

If you want to get to a higher wine version you will need to install [Play On Linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) and install a higher version from there.